# Mate - change background of login page after suspend

Tags: 16.04, lightdm, mate, ubuntu-mate, desktop-background

I have ubuntu Mate 16.04 on my laptop. I am trying to change the background page of the screen that appears after the laptop has been closed.

I changed the bg of the login page (when I power) by:

`/etc/lightdm/lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf`

But the other page no.

How can I do?

Comment: Interesting question. Try to ask on https://ubuntu-mate.community/ .

Answer (score 0):

Text taken from the solution on [mate forum](https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/how-to-change-the-lock-screen-background-of-mate-on-ubuntu-mate-15-04/1732)

Create `/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/z-mate.gschema.override`.

The content of `z-mate.gschema.override`  should be:

```
[org.mate.background]
picture-filename='/path/to/background'
```

Now, you have to compile gsettings schemas with the command below:

`sudo glib-compile-schemas /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/`

And It worked for me, with UMate 16.04 lts.